# Right way to use md5 secrets in confirming ok-ness of URL requests? When to clear the secret?

Tags: php, security, session-variables

I have some cases where I need to put a URL into a web page that, when clicked on, will fire some handling code on the server.  I obviously want to prevent random bad guys from constructing their own URLs and doing things they shouldn't, so I'm working with this scheme, reverse-engineered from stuff I've seen on other sites:

- make a unique string (I'm using MD5, but there doubtless other options)
- put this string into an appropriately named session variable
- include the string in the URL, maybe something like `/do_this/123/FABDYFYEYYDFBDHDFS`
- when the handling code runs, extract the string from the url and compare it to the value of the session variable -- if it matches, we should be safe to proceed.  If not, do something else.

This is working OK for me, except for the part where the user's browser's session storage gets littered with no-longer-relevant session variables.  There are some cases where I can (and do) delete a session variable once I'm done doing what I'm doing, but not always.  I could probably be a little more clever about finding opportunities to clear the old variables, but the problem seems general enough that there may be a better way to do this (i.e., what I've come up with could be really stupid for any number of reasons I haven't thought of).  Is there any advice out there for a good/better way of doing this sort of thing?

Comment: If you can validate the ok-ness of the URL (as you do in the first page, otherwise how can you know the URL to md5?), then why not calculate this on the second page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding the question, but I'm not sure why you need to store the unique string in a session variable / cookie at all. Why not do something like:

- Render the page with the secret string in the `<a>` tags or wherever.
- Store the string as being "okay" server-side.
- When the string is used to fire an event, invalidate it. This works automagically if your links result in page reloads, but it could also be achieved with AJAX or etc.

Comment: I need to store the string *somewhere* on the server side to be able to do the test when trying to execute the event; I happened to use a session variable because, well, it was easy.  I could write it into my database in some sort of user-specific way, but that doesn't solve the problem of when the string is safe to delete.  I've been deleting it in some cases when I can be sure that I'm done with it, but there are other times (no page reload) when this won't work, as you note.  But... (see next comment)

Comment: ...maybe I'm doing this wrong?  I'm using md5 to generate a random and presumably unique string; perhaps the right thing to do is, on page creation, build a meaningful string (username, action name, time, random) and encrypt it; I can then decrypt it in the event test.  This way I don't need the session variable or whatever, although I'd need some sort of storage if I wanted to limit it to one-time usage.  I think....

Comment: In general, I would recommend not building "meaningful" strings because they are inherently easier to guess (even if you "encrypt" it). When I do things like session keys, I usually just get 32 bytes or something from a **cryptographically secure** random number generator (**not** `rand` or `mt_rand`), and then convert it to hex, and then send that. As for storage, yeah, you need to store the string server-side, but **not** client-side (other than in the page source), as you originally were saying (*"...the user's browser's session storage gets littered..."*).

Comment: Thanks! But I confess I still don't see a solution to the problem of "when can I get rid of the stored version of the secret?" -- it seems like something, somewhere is going to be gathering up these obsolete things.  I guess the fact that it's uncertain when these can be deleted means that there is no obvious answer out there that I've missed.  I'll buy the notion that session vars are an unsatisfactory place to save them; maybe stick them in a database with a timestamp and purge them after some amount of time has passed?

Comment: The only place they need to be stored is in the database server-side, and embedded in the HTML when you render the page. As for deleting them, you could do something like ensure only one will exist for each user at a time - replacing it as needed, or you could use some NoSQL database like MongoDB or Redis or etc. which allow you to set the expiration of data, so it'll be automatically deleted. Or you could always run a cron job to execute a script that will delete old ones.

Comment: I'm kinda bound to mysql, so I'll probably go the cron route.  Thanks for walking me through this!